# How do I split a string into a List of chars in F sharp

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

How do I split string into a list of chars in F sharp  for example if I want to split the word "Hello" into a list of chars ie.

```
"Hello" ->['H';'e';'l';'l';'o']
```

I have tried  **Split([| |])** but it only splits a string depending on the parameter u pass in.

I have tried this to but it still did not work

```
let splitChar (text:string) = 
    [for c in text ->c] 

let splitChar (text:string) = 
    [for c in text do yield c]
```

Comment: You don't need to split anything. The characters are already available through the [String.Chars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Answer (score 31):

You can use `Seq.toList` to convert a string to a list of characters:

```
Seq.toList "Hello"
```

Comment: That works because a string is already a sequence of characters. There's no need to use `Seq.toList` to work with individual characters

Comment: True, and it would be helpful for the question to be clarified so that we know _why_ OP wants specifically a list as output. The result of `Seq.toList "Hello"` gives a `char list` as output

Comment: When I use seq.toLIst the compiler complains that "The field constructor toList is not defined

Comment: It should be a capital `S` in `Seq`. Also, the first instance has a capital `I` in `toLIst` in your example, when it should be capitalized as `toList`

Answer (score 13):

A string is essentially a sequence of characters, as it [implements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) `IEnumerable<char>`. Internally, a string is an array of char values. That array is exposed through the [Chars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) indexer.

You can use any `Seq` method on a string, eg :

```
"abc" |> Seq.iter (fun x->printfn "%c" x)
```

Individual characters are also available

You can also use the optimized functions of the [String module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.string-module-%5bfsharp%5d) :

```
"abc" |> String.iter (fun x->printfn "%c" x)
```

The `String` module uses the methods of the `String` class to improve performance. For example, the [String.length](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/string.fs#L97) function is an alias for the `String.Length` property, so it doesn't have to iterate over all characters like `Seq` would do:

```
    let length (str:string) =
        let str = emptyIfNull str
        str.Length
```

Other functions, like [String.iter](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/string.fs#L26) use the `Chars` indexer directly :

```
    let iter (f : (char -> unit)) (str:string) =
        let str = emptyIfNull str
        for i = 0 to str.Length - 1 do
            f str.[i]
```

Answer (score 6):

In .NET, you can use [String.ToCharArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray) method. To get back into a String, you can use [String(Char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String__ctor_System_Char___) now that F# using constructors as functions.

```
"Hello".ToCharArray() |> List.ofArray
```

It may be better performance to just use the F# Array module. I'm guessing `List.ofArray` is more efficient than `List.ofSeq`. If that doesn't matter, similar to Chad's answer, the F# idiomatic way is:

```
"Hello" |> List.ofSeq
```

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed occasions where I would initially think to split something into a char array or a list first - but where I should be more succinct.

```
let msg = "hello-world"

let resultA = 
    msg.[0..0].ToUpper() + msg.[1..].Replace('-', ' ')

let resultB = 
    Seq.toList (msg)
    |> (fun list -> (string list.Head).ToUpper() + (String.Concat(list.Tail)).Replace('-', ' '))

// val resultA : string = "Hello world"
// val resultB : string = "Hello world"
```

The 'resultA' way is nicer I think.